# Botframework - Update welcome message sent from OnMembersAddedAsync

Tags: botframework

I have a simple botframework bot used from teams. It is a personal bot, that writes a short welcome message the first time the user adds it. I doesn't allow the user to write to the bot (it is a notification bot).

However, now I want to update the original welcome message, but for users that have already recieved it, the `OnMembersAddedAsync` method is never called again.

How would I go around getting the new updated welcome message to all users of the bot?

I see that I can uninstall the bot, give it a new id and install it again. But that seems like a big work around.

I guess if I had stored the activityId from the original message, it could have edited the message, but I didnt do that, so not a feasible solution.

Is there no way to get triggered when the users opens the that with the bot again?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for that method to be triggered again. Teams maintains their own history, and it's tied to the bot id. The only way to reset it is to delete the bot entirely, which is a bad plan.

Have you looked into proactive messaging? You could trigger a one time proactive message that LOOKS like a welcome message, but isn't.

Comment: Yes I know about proactive messages, I was just hoping I could rectify my mistake of not having used them from the beginning. However how would you trigger a proactive message as a welcome message, still using the OnMembersAdded hook? Or using ConversationUpdated, the using my own statemanagement